# Nested JsonSubType using JacksonMapper in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, deserialization

I have a message delivery system which can be either a push notification, or sms or ...
and each of these can have their own subtypes, like Sms can be Irancell or Mediana or ...

I want to use JsonSubType to find out the class of my message and use their corresponding sending mechanism.

here is my code:

```
class MedianaSmsMessage(
    override val receiver: String,
    override val message: Message,
    override val app: App,
    override val requester: DeliveryRequester,
    override val deliveryProviderId: String,
    override val smsDeliveryType: String = "MEDIANA",
) : SmsMessageForDelivery()
```

and this is the SmsMessageForDelivery class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "smsDeliveryType", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MedianaSmsMessage::class, name = "MEDIANA"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = IrancellSmsMessage::class, name = "IRANCELL"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MobinnetSmsMessage::class, name = "MOBINNET"),
)
abstract class SmsMessageForDelivery : MessageForDelivery() {
    abstract override val receiver: String
    abstract override val message: Message
    override val deliveryType: DeliveryType = DeliveryType.SMS
    abstract override val app: App
    abstract override val requester: DeliveryRequester
    abstract override val deliveryProviderId: String
    abstract val smsDeliveryType: String
```

and this is the MessageForDelivery class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "deliveryType", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PushMessageForDelivery::class, name = "APP_PUSH"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = WebHookMessageForDelivery::class, name = "WEBHOOK"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EmailMessageForDelivery::class, name = "EMAIL"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SmsMessageForDelivery::class, name = "SMS"),
)

abstract class MessageForDelivery {
    abstract val receiver: String
    abstract val message: Message
    abstract val deliveryType: DeliveryType
    abstract val app: App
    abstract val requester: DeliveryRequester
    abstract val deliveryProviderId: String
}
```

but when I writeAsString a MedianaSmsMessage class, I can't deserialize it using the MessageForDelivery:

```
@PostConstruct
    fun test(){
        val content = "{\"smsDeliveryType\":\"MEDIANA\",\"receiver\":\"+9891312331\",\"message\":{\"title\":\"sms-title\",\"body\":\"test\",\"link\":null,\"url\":null,\"icon\":null,\"images\":[],\"buttons\":[]},\"app\":{\"appId\":\"test\"},\"requester\":{\"type\":\"CAMPAIGN\",\"id\":\"63e8b35acedd7f451fd0da14\"},\"deliveryProviderId\":\"Mediana\",\"deliveryType\":\"SMS\"}"
        val medianaSms = mapper.readValue(
            content,
            MedianaSmsMessage::class.java
        )
        val t = mapper.writeValueAsString(medianaSms)
        val test = mapper.readValue(t, MessageForDelivery::class.java)
        println(test)
    }
```

this is giving me the error:

```
Cannot construct instance of `ir.pegahtech.metrix.delivery.push.services.models.message.sms.SmsMessageForDelivery` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

Answer (score 0):

You deserialize twice in this code:

```
val medianaSms = mapper.readValue(
    content,
    MedianaSmsMessage::class.java
)
val t = mapper.writeValueAsString(medianaSms)
val test = mapper.readValue(t, MessageForDelivery::class.java)
```

The first works correctly (this shows your class structures and annotations are all good). The second does not.

In principle this kind of deserialization to an abstract/interface should work, but in your case I think it is the double layer of classses.  If you ask the mapper to deserialize using `MessageForDelivery` I think it fails because it does not have sufficient information to know how do deserialize the full hierarchy.  This is odd, because the error refers to the concrete class... so it was able to track to that point? I don't know why.

Deserializing like this does work, but is obviously functionally different:

```
val test = mapper.readValue(t, SmsMessageForDelivery::class.java)
```

Perhaps you can restructure your hierarchy to get to a single use of `@JsonTypeInfo`/`@JsonSubTypes` ?

Comment: actually I added a handler for when it fails and it seems to work! but I don't like it. seems like a patch!